# WebApi rest Webservice with database connection

Tags: mysql, rest, asp.net-web-api

I created an example rest webservice using `WebApi`.
Here is the controller class named  `Employee Controller`.

```
namespace HelloWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {
        private static IList<Employee> list = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee()
            {
            Id = 12345, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Human",Department = 2
            },
            new Employee()
            {
            Id = 12346, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Public",Department = 3
            },
            new Employee()
            {
            Id = 12347, FirstName = "Joseph", LastName = "Law",Department = 2
            }
        };
 // GET api/employees
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
        {
            return list;
        }

        // GET api/employees/12345
        public Employee Get(int id)
        {
            return list.First(e => e.Id == id);
        }
        // POST api/employees
        public void Post(Employee employee)
        {
            int maxId = list.Max(e => e.Id);
            employee.Id = maxId + 1;
            list.Add(employee);
        }
        // PUT api/employees/12345
        public void Put(int id, Employee employee)
        {
            int index = list.ToList().FindIndex(e => e.Id == id);
            list[index] = employee;
        }
        // DELETE api/employees/12345
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            Employee employee = Get(id);
            list.Remove(employee);
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Patch(int id, Delta<Employee> deltaEmployee)
        {
            var employee = list.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            deltaEmployee.Patch(employee);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I used all HTTP verbs method for insert, update, delete. I used a list that stores the Employee objects. insertion, deletion and updation are based on this list. But this program has no database connection. I want to know how to use Database access in this program. I would like to use tables from a database. How could i do it? Any useful link please.

Comment: @Aliostad yes. I googled so much. But i cant find a the program to connect with database.

Comment: see here https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=web+api+entity+framework&oq=webapi+entity+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5032j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8